# Return true php

Tags: php

A friend got this question during an interview:

What should be the value of x so that the following function returns true.

```
<?php
function returnTrue( $x ){
    $x[$x] = $x;
    return $x != true;
}
$res = returnTrue(YOUR_ANSWER);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

The answer should be 3 characters max

Comment: The title is too ambiguous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was interesting, I gave this test a quick try and the answer is :

```
$res = returnTrue([]);
```

Comment: did you notice that your code will trigger an illegal offset warning?I think that a question designed for an interview can't lead to this type of error.But it is just an opinion....

Answer (score 2):

of course this

```
returntrue([]);
```

works 
but not completely fine as you would receive the message

> Warning:  Illegal offset type in ....

You must keep in my in mind that string type also allows arrayAccess style so

the right answer is

```
$res=returntrue('0');
var_dump($res)// print true
```

When you give as argument the string `'0'` this code `$x[$x]=$x` give again the same string `'0'`
wich will not produce any warning and will absolutely return true as the `string '0'` will always be evaluated as `false` and `false!=true` return `true`

Comment: A better (and probably the correct) solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

And also for the other post now deleted, I also managed to solve it.

```
function returnTrue( $x )
{
    if( !is_array( $x ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach( $x as $x ) {
        $x[] = $x;
    }
    return $x;
}

var_dump(returnTrue([!0]));
```